# How to fix keypress event for enter key that is running a function twice while only being called once

Tags: javascript, function, keypress, iife

I am creating a tip calculator. I have a button on the page that calculates the tip if you press it or if you press enter on the keyboard. When I press the enter key, the function that calculates the tip runs but then it runs again even though I did not call it again anywhere in my code. The odd thing is, is that the second time it runs, it goes into the variable where the function is stored and runs the function. I don't know why it goes into a variable that wasn't called.

I tried debugging to see if I missed a step and if I called the function twice somewhere, but I didn't.

Here is the keypress event:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.keycode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
        calculateTip();
      }
```

Then right after that code is the calculateTip variable:

```
var calculateTip = function() {
   some code that does calculations
}
```

After the key is pressed, calculateTip is executed, then it goes straight into the above variable to run calculateTip again.

I have my code inside an IIFE. I already tested to see if the code outside of this IIFE affected anything, it doesn't. The 'click' event listener works perfectly and only executes the calculateTip function once.
In this version of my code, calculateTip will print 'test' to the console twice if enter is clicked.

The IIFE:

```
var controller = (function(calcCtrl, UICtrl) {

  var setupEventListeners = function() {

    var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

    document.querySelector(DOM.button).addEventListener('click', calculateTip);

    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.keycode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
        calculateTip();
      }
    });
  };

var calculateTip = function() {
 console.log('test')
};

return {
    init: function() {
      setupEventListeners();
    }
  }

})(calculateController, UIController);

controller.init();
```

Comment: put a print statement inside eventListener if (keycode == 13) and inside calculateTip. Then you will be able to see which of the tow functions are called twice.

Comment: @Radagast I added a print statement inside calculateTip and it printed twice. I don't know why since I only called calculateTip once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with jquery you can solve it

```
$(document).unbind('keypress').bind('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keycode === 13 || e.which === 13) {
    calculateTip();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `event.preventDefault();` inside the callback, it helped me.

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keycode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        calculateTip();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's give one time would you please check this out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
          if (event.keycode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
            calculateTip();
          }
     });
    var calculateTip = function() {
       console.log("enter clicked");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the following to your event listener function:

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Comment: For me it is working in IE, Chrome, Firefox, so I need more info what could help to reproducte the problem. Is that the only code what you have? Which browser is producing that thing and which version? Isn't there other code which has effect to this piece of code? Have you tried with ananother key to see it is happening nut just with enter? Are you not triggering keypress somewhere programatically?

Comment: It turns out that I did not need the keypress function because if I pressed the enter key, calculateTip would run anyways, but that only works if I tab to the corresponding button on the document. I am thinking that it the function was executed twice because I added the keypress function. I am not sure why the enter key works without any code though.